# Примеры, когда и двоеточие, и тире будут правильными вариантами

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, тире-или-двоеточие

1. Приведите примеры с пояснениями, когда и двоеточие, и тире будут правильным вариантом написания.
2. Следующее предложение подходит?

> Выходные – 22, 23. (Выходные: 22, 23.)

Comment: Знаки разные, поэтому, даже если взять такие примеры, одно и то же не получится.

Comment: Нет, даже не почти, интонация совсем другая, смысловые отношения отличаются. Разве что просто похожее. Хотя в таких примерах, как у вас, сходство больше всего. Но не в тему здесь двоеточие, потому что тогда оно как объявление и нужен ещё месяц. Но вы можете придумать пример без дат. И ещё: всегда есть лучший вариант (и это не субъективно), он среди прочего зависит от цели, а от цели зависит стиль.

Comment: В этом примере не пояснение, а сказуемое. Просто грамматика. При изъятии пояснения предложение не ломается...